# Cannot turn off keyboard backlight on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu `22.04` on a laptop which has an LED keyboard and after the latest OS update the keyboard LED's come on and won't turn off no matter what I do.

There's a keyboard shortcut for controlling the LED's which is no longer working and I've also trying setting the brightness manually using the `brightnessctl` tool but that didn't work.

Running `uname -a` returns:

```
6.5.0-14-generic #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas how I can work around that? I just need to turn the LED's off.

Thanks

Comment: It may be a kernel bug. What is the kernel  version? Use the command `uname -a` and copy and paste the output into the question above. Use the [Edit button above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1500430/edit). Try booting to the last kernel using GRUB and see if the keyboard backlight can be turned off. Add if it works with the old kernel in your question. If it works with the old kernel and does not work with the new kernel, [File a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: hi @user68186 thanks for that, I just pasted the output of the `uname` command in the question above. Ok, I see, I'll try to do that, thanks!

Comment: See [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version) for booting the previous version of the kernel. See the answer by Jackkobec.